# Trying to delete record by CRUD route::delete method(Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Larave's framework program with deleting by CRUDS method DELETE.

My route method is:

```
 Route::delete('cats/{cat}/delete', function(Furbook\Cat $cat){
 $cat->delete();    return redirect('cats.index')       
 ->withSuccess('Cat
 has been deleted.'); });
```

My view with delete url:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('header')
<a href="{{ url('/') }}">Back to the overview</a>
<h2>
    {{ $cat->name }}

</h2>
<a href="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/edit') }}">
    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
    Edit    
</a>
<a href ="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete') }}">
    <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    Delete
</a>
<p>Last edited: {{ $cat->updated_at }}</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
<p>Date of Birth: {{ $cat->date_of_birth }} </p>
<p>
    @if ($cat->breed)
    Breed:
     {{ url('cats/breeds/'.$cat->breed->name) }} 
    @endif

</p>
@endsection
```

My Cat model:

```
<?php 

namespace Furbook;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cat extends Model {
    // We specified the fields that are fillable in the Cat model beforehand
    protected $fillable = ['name','date_of_birth','breed_id'];
    // informacja o tym, żeby nie uaktualniać update_at w tabeli kotów
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function breed(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Furbook\Breed');
    }
}
?>
```

When I'm clicking on delete link, there is an error like this:

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

I don't know what's wrong. Could you somoene help me with solving problem?

Could someone help me with this problem?
I would be very grateful, greetings.

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is emitted when you access a route which exists but does not listen for the request method you're using. Namely you're accessing the `delete` route via a `GET` request.

Answer (score 3):

This is to do with the Request you are making. You must either create form with the delete method like so

```
<form action="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete') }}" method="DELETE">
    <button class ="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</button>
</form>
```

OR change your route to a get

```
Route::get('cats/{cat}/delete', function(Furbook\Cat $cat){
     $cat->delete();    
     return redirect('cats.index')->withSuccess('Cat has been deleted.');      
});
```

If you go the form route don't for get to add the {{ csrf_field() }}

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Answer (score 2):

Using `Route::delete()`, you cannot place it in an anchor. Make a form with `DELETE` method.

```
{!! Form::model($cat, ['method' => 'DELETE', 'url' => 'cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete']) !!}
    <button type="submit">Delete</a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```